# Rails Paperclip adds extra folder pointing to Cloudfront (between :url and :path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, path, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

I'm having trouble with loading images uploaded to s3 via my cloudfront distribution. I can get it to work fine loading straight from s3, but not from cloudfront.
I have set the config.action_controller.asset_host to my distribution url and have set up paperclip

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_host_name => 's3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com',
:url => ':asset_host',
:s3_credentials => {
:bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
:secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}
}
```

with the appropriate code in the model :path =>

```
':class/:id/:style/:class:style:id.:extension'
```

and every time I upload a file and try to access it i get

```
https://XXXXXX.cloudfront.net/images/:class/:id/:style/:class:style:id.:extension
```

I honestly can't figure out where the /images/ is coming from that is added between the url and the path. And I would be very greatful for any help or tips to solve this!
Thanks

Comment: is it a problem with the url or with the path? in other words, is the image being stored at `:class/:id/:style/:class:style:id.:extension` or at /images/:class/:id/:style/:class:style:id.:extension?

Comment: the image is being stored in :class/:id/:style/:class:style:id.:extension.
But when I try to access it with erb 
<%= image_tag homeImage.image.url(:original)%>
I get https://XXXXXX.cloudfront.net/images/:class/:id/:style/:class:style:id.:extension
The issue is that '/images' is being added to the img src url.
If you have any ideas, they would be greatly apreciated. Thank you Nicolas.

Comment: post the HomeImage model please

Comment: `class HomeImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :by_rank, -> {where(rank:true)}
  def self.to_rank
    order('rank asc')
  end

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :original => "1500x"},
  :path => '/:class/:id/:style/:class:style:id.:extension'
  
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
 :image_file_name
 :image_content_type
 :image_file_size
 :image_updated_at
 :logoWhite
 :rank
end`

sorry for the delayed response! Any help would be appreciated!